# Add component to window when button is clicked

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, jbutton

The following class creates a window with a `JPanel` container. This container contains a `JPanel` filled with `JTextFields`, and a `JPanel` with a `JButton` on it. Looks like this: 
[image: Picture of my window]

When I click the button I want it to add another `JTextField` to the left `JPanel` and I wonder how I should do this. Should I:

- Change the existing left `JPanel` in some way?
- Create a new `JPanel` with a larger GridLayout, add the things I want in it (current items + an extra `JTextField`), and then add the `JPanel` to my window, somehow replacing my current `JPanel`?
- Do something else?

Below is my code in its entirety. Copy, paste and run it if you like. Any help is appreciated!

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;    
public class PanelUpdateTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int row = 4;
        int col = 6;

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();                //the Window
        JPanel container = new JPanel();            //A panel that contains all components

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();          
        JButton button = new JButton("Add Text Field");     
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){             
                System.out.println("Button \"Add Text Field\" was clicked.");
                //here i want code to add another JTextField to the window.
            }
        });     
        buttonPanel.add(button);

        container.add(createPanel(row, col));
        container.add(buttonPanel);

        frame.add(container);       

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);     
    }

    /**
     * This method returns a JPanel filled with JTextFields.
     */
    public static JPanel createPanel(int row, int col){
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setLayout(new GridLayout(row, col));
        for(int i = 0; i < row*col; i++){
            jp.add(new JTextField("  Text  "));
        }       
        return jp;
    }
}
```

Comment: It all kind of depends on how you want it to look once you have executed this. What's your desired effect? Adding a row and squishing everything up?

Comment: I want it to have 4 rows with 6 JTextField and a 5th row with 1 JTextField.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have several recommendations for you in order to resolve this problem.
First and foremost is your means of actually displaying your panels. If I continue to add panels continuously on subsequent rows, then they are not all visible in the frame without resizing.

For this reason, I would recommend use of the `JScrollPane` to house your panel returned by `createPanel`. You can read documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html).

Next is your issue of using this `GridLayout`. While it's great to define the number of rows you want for your text fields, you don't need to specify in the `GridLayout`. If you define either parameter as 0 in the layout, it continuously fills in that direction. So, I would replace `new GridLayout(row, col)` with `new GridLayout(0,col)`. That way, your columns are filled but you can have unlimited rows.

Now, in order to modify your `JPanel` and add more text fields to it, you need to provide access. For this reason, I would recommend making `JPanel jp` into a static variable and simply instantiate it inside of the method.

Why make it static? Because you are dealing with all static methods and need to provide access to inside of the `ActionListener`. If you were doing this all in a derived `JFrame` class that implemented the interface, you could do it with an instance variable.

Your code would look something like this:

```
public static JPanel jp = null;
public static JPanel createPanel(int row, int column)
{
    jp = new JPanel();
    //etc etc
}
```

Lastly is actually adding your `JTextFields`. To do this inside of your `ActionListener`, first check to ensure that `jp` is not null. Then, simply add your text field and then call `jp.revalidate();`. This forces the updates to be shown.

Hope this makes sense to you! Happy to answer any other questions over the code or any reasoning I have in doing it this way!

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! This really helped!

Answer (score 1):

> •Create a new JPanel with a larger GridLayout

You don't need a larger GridLayout. The layout changes dynamically as you add/remove components to the panel.

> I want it to have 4 rows with 6 JTextField and a 5th row with 1 JTextField.

You create the GridLayout like:

```
JPanel = new JPanel( new GridLayout(0, 6) );
```

Then you add 25 text fields to the panel. The layout will automatically wrap after the 6th component is added for a given row.

Answer (score 0):

I think You should look at paint()/repaint()/update() methods in java.awt.Component. 
[Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html)

Comment: You should not use paint() or update(). When you add components to a visible GUI you do a revalidate() and repaint() on the JPanel.